# Pair together light curve and radial velocity data of specified star

Tags: exoplanet, kepler, nasa, light-curve, radial-velocity

I would like to create a web application that works with light curves and radial velocities of stars with exoplanets. I found a [NASA bulk data download](https://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/bulk_data_download/) with both light curves and radial velocities (it's exactly what I'm looking for). However, I don't know how to pair together the light curve and radial velocity of a single star (without downloading the whole dataset).

For example, using the script below I can download the light curve of KIC 10666592, where there is 1 exoplanet:

```
wget -O 'kplr010666592-2009131110544_slc.fits' 'http://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu:80/data/ETSS//Kepler/005/755/19/kplr010666592-2009131110544_slc.fits' -a search_33681064.log
```

Now, how can I download radial velocity data for this specific star? Scripts for radial velocity look like (there is no KIC in URL):

```
wget -O UID_0000522_RVC_001.tbl http://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu:80/data/ExoData/0000/0000522/data/UID_0000522_RVC_001.tbl -a RADIAL.log
```

Is there any way to connect KIC (Kepler input catalog) and radial velocity UID?

Comment: Can you describe a webpage how / where I'd find the latter URL linked or data access to that file type described? I find readily the Kepler data, the light curves... but RV data I don't see

Comment: Radial velocity data for 1072 exoplanets are located in the last table on the page (data set with name RADIAL). But I don't require this dataset. If you know of another dataset, I can use that one as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An excellent page to get most or all names for a star is [Simbad](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-fid) which also happens to know the Kepler IDs (KID).

Ont the other hand, every of the RV data files contains info on the star's identifier it belongs to in the header, e.g:

> \STAR_ID='HD 4628'

So using Simbad you should be able to do a cross-matching. SimBad allows scripted query and includes all alias names for stars; thus query for one known star name and look for identifiers found in the list of RV-observed stars or vice versa. Simbad allows to be queried via scripts, so you can make a short programme to do this task for you.

However I'm not 100% convinced that you necessarily find many matches between those two data sets; it's easier to do photometry than spectroscopy.